# How to get timeline link from Facebook Graph API in v2.7

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Under certain conditions, the Facebook Graph API returns an app-scoped user ID. With this ID you cannot access the timeline of a user in the usual fashion (`https://facebook.com/<app_scoped_user_id>`).

I know there's a `link` field on the [`user` node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user) and a [`user_link` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-user_link) but it only returns a value in v3.0.

How can I get this value in v2.7?

Comment: You can’t, they removed this. You need explicit permission from the user now, and if you want that, you’ll have to use v3.

Comment: I see. Too bad. Thanks for the comment.